# how to check if a folder is open in file explorer using autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I am using <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+T</kbd> to open cmd prompt int the curent open folder using

```
^!t::Send !d {enter} cmd {enter}
```

But while pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+T</kbd> in browser or in desktop nothing happens or opens random applications. Can I check if file explorer is open and run this command else 
open some default folder in cmd prompt. Thanks

Comment: Oh well. I'll open the documentation for you.

Comment: -1 for not having read the FAQ: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm#HotContext

Comment: Thanks for -1. Motivated me to searching answer myself.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the answer folks...

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass
^!t::Send !d cmd {enter}
```